# Referência não encontrada para propriedade de objeto

Tags: javascript, canvas, console, referência

Desenvolvi um código simples de particulas no codepen.io e na sua execução gera um log com o erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined
```

Qual o motivo do erro?

```js
// inicia o canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    W = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
    H = canvas.height = window.innerHeight,
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function rI(min, max, mode){
  if (mode = 'int'){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min) + min);
  }else{
    return Math.random() * (max-min) + min;
  }
}

function genSpeed(min, max, excludeMin, excludeMax){
 var speed;
 do{
    speed = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  }while(speed > excludeMin && speed < excludeMax)
  return speed;
}

function createDot(){
  //engine
  this.posX = rI(0, W+1);
  this.posY = rI(0, H+1);
  this.speX = rI(-5, 5,-2,2);
  this.speY = rI(-5, 5,-2,2);
//   this.speX = genSpeed(-5, 5, -1, 1);
//   this.speY = genSpeed(-5, 5, -1, 1);
  
  //style
  this.size = rI(5, 30);
  this.color = 'rgb('+rI(0,256)+','+rI(0,256)+','+rI(0,256)+')';
}

var dots = [];
for(var i = 0; i <= 15; i++){
    dots.push(new createDot());
}

function run(){
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
  for(var j = 0; j <= dots.length; j++){
    
    
    var d = dots[j];

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = d.color; //**O erro no console aponta pra cá**
    ctx.arc(d.posX, d.posY, d.size, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fill();
    
    d.posX += d.speX;
    d.posY += d.speY;
    
    if (d.posX < W + d.size && d.posX > W) d.speX *= -1;
    if (d.posX < 0 - d.size && d.posX < 0) d.speX *= -1;
    if (d.posY < H + d.size && d.posY > H) d.speY *= -1;
    if (d.posY < 0 - d.size && d.posY < 0) d.speY *= -1;
    
  }
}

setInterval(run, 1);

// alert(dots.posX.toString());
```

```css
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Aqui está a pen
[Particulas](http://codepen.io/GabrielMaia/full/gbmBrp/)

Comment: Poste o código aqui, dando indicações claras de onde está o erro.

Comment: Atualizei o post bigown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na função `run`, você está percorrendo para uma posição que o conjunto de pontos não tem registro.

```
for(var j = 0; j <= dots.length; j++){ <- errado
for(var j = 0; j < dots.length; j++){  <- correto
```

Veja o teste do `for`.

[Link para pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogZmyv)

Comment: Realmente, agradeço

Comment: Mas agora eu me pergunto o porque só a propriedade colors não foi encontrada, sendo que outras foram utilizadas...

Comment: O relatório do console javascript não é 100% preciso. Se eu comentasse a linha da propriedade colors, ele iria reclamar de outra coisa.

Comment: hmmm entendi, valeu man :)